# Odoo Validate invoice through API : Request has no attribute session

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

I am running Odoo on a vps server.

I try to validate an invoice through python XMLrpc using this command

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.move', 'action_post',[moveId])
```

with

```
models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
```

It works inconsistently. Sometimes it works, sometimes I get this  [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E22JV.png) that ends with a message

> AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'session'.

On some occasions (no difference between working cases and not working cases) the invoice actually gets validated through API.

I noticed that when I activate / deactivate developper mode, the first invoice i try to validate works but not the ones after

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you ever find a solution? (Currently using a while loop that tries infinitely until success, I get on average 5 success, 2 fails.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have any changes in the model but Session errors generally comes from not defining Odoo environment correctly. Please check that. Also as the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/howtos/web_services.html) (Note section) suggests you can use high level APIs.